# How to change permission only inside the directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, samba

I think this is a weird question, I don't know if it is possible, but here I go:

I have a shared directory in a server, so people can use it from their computers, so let's say I have a directory call **Mantenimientos/** and inside it I have two other directories **Fisico/** and **Logico/** I want people to have permission to write into those last directories, but I don't want them to have permission to change those directories names or move them.

Is that possible?

*OS: Solaris 10 5/08*

*English is not my native tongue, if there's something you can't understand please ask, and any correction is welcome as well.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renaming directories requires write permission in the *parent* directory, so let's say you have

```
BASE
BASE/Mantenimientos
BASE/Mantenimientos/Fiscio
BASE/Mantenimientos/Logico
```

The `Mantenimientos` directory would be made `r-x`, and the `Fiscio` and `Logico` directories would be `rwx` permission.

e.g.

```
$ ls -ld Mantenimientos                                                        
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Aug 30 13:04 Mantenimientos/

$ cd Mantenimientos
$ ls -Al
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Aug 30 13:04 Fiscio/
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Aug 30 13:04 Logico/
```

So I can write to the two directories, but not to the `Mantenimientos` directory.  This means I can not rename them

```
$ mv Fiscio changed                                                            
mv: cannot move 'Fiscio' to 'changed': Permission denied
```

But I can create files

```
$ echo a file > Fiscio/file1                                                   
$ echo another > Logico/file2   
$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, exactly what I was looking for... but now my question looks really dumb haha anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not a dumb question; it's a relatively common one for people learning about the unix permission model.  But obvious once you understand it :-)